# AWK - Lookup data in lookup file and Print "success" or "Failure"

Tags: unix, awk

Having trouble working out what I need to achieve in AWK. I have 2 files:

Data File:-

```
XYZ:ABC:tab1:join_check:abc111:abc.tab1234
XYZ:ABC:tab2:join_check:abc112:abc.tab1234
XYZ:ABC:tab3:join_check:abc113:abc.tab1234
XYZ:NON-ABC:tab1:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234
XYZ:NON-ABC:tab2:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234
HQL:ABC:tab1:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234
HQL:NON-ABC:tab2:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234
HQL:NON-ABC:tab3:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234
```

Lookup File:-

```
XYZ:ABC:tab1
XYZ:ABC:tab2
XYZ:NON-ABC:tab1
HQL:ABC:tab1
HQL:NON-ABC:tab2
```

Desired Output:-

```
XYZ:ABC:tab1:join_check:abc111:abc.tab1234:Verified
XYZ:ABC:tab2:join_check:abc112:abc.tab1234:Verified
XYZ:ABC:tab3:join_check:abc113:abc.tab1234:Failed
XYZ:NON-ABC:tab1:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234:Verified
XYZ:NON-ABC:tab2:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234:Failed
HQL:ABC:tab1:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234:Verified
HQL:NON-ABC:tab2:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234:Verified
HQL:NON-ABC:tab3:join_check:abc123:abc.tab1234:Failed
```

Using the First 3 Fields from Data Files, need to do lookup on the Lookup file for the same three fields. If the record/entry  is found (all three fields match), need to print line from Data file and append "Verified" else if record/entry is not found, need to print line from data file and append "Failed".

Any help is in this regards is much appreciated

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question as its highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NR==FNR{lookup[$1":"$2":"$3]=1; next} {print $0, (lookup[$1":"$2":"$3] ? "Verified" : "Failed")}' lookup data
```

First we have two blocks of code, the first is only executed for the lookup file (first file) and the second only for the data file (second file). This is done by checking the FNR (file record number) and NR (overall record number). This is only the same for the first file, so NR==FRN, and then we jump to the next line using `next` to prevent the second block from being executed for the first file.

Then for the second file, we lookup the tree fields in the lookup associative array and select "Verified" if found or "Failed" if not found using a ternary operator.

We then print the whole line $0 with that new field. We set field separator and output field separator resp. with `-F: -v OFS=:`.

Comment: @NaveenThimmappa If you think the answer is satisfactory you can accept the answer so that other people know this question is answered.